# Should we create a schema per "project"?

Tags: sql-server, performance, schema

This is a database where users create a 'project' and work on it. We have a table for `project` and various other tables that contain different attributes for project (multiple rows for each project from 2-30K rows). All of them contains `projectID` as link to `project`.  Currently the database is 400GB.

We are trying to create a schema for each project wherein each schema would contain all attribute tables. Whenever a project is created, it would get a new schema.  This would be mean each table would contain at max 30K rows which would improve `select` performance. We would be using dynamic SQL in our queries to read/insert.

I feel like this would not be proper application of database but how do I prove to my team that this a bad approach?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read this paper: [Multi-Tenant Data Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). It extensively discusses on the pros and cons of 3 possible approaches (tenant ID in each table, schema per tenant, database per tenant). This approach is called ["Shared database, Separate schemas"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx#mlttntda_sdss) and is a valid approach.  Whether it is best for your case, I'm not in position to make that call. This is what the paper has to say about this approach:

> A significant drawback of the separate-schema approach is that tenant
> data is harder to restore in the event of a failure. If each tenant
> has its own database, restoring a single tenant's data means simply
> restoring the database from the most recent backup. With a
> separate-schema application, restoring the entire database would mean
> overwriting the data of every tenant on the same database with backup
> data, regardless of whether each one has experienced any loss or not.
> Therefore, to restore a single customer's data, the database
> administrator may have to restore the database to a temporary server,
> and then import the customer's tables into the production server—a
> complicated and potentially time-consuming task.
>
> The separate schema
> approach is appropriate for applications that use a relatively small
> number of database tables, on the order of about 100 tables per tenant
> or fewer. This approach can typically accommodate more tenants per
> server than the separate-database approach can, so you can offer the
> application at a lower cost, as long as your customers will accept
> having their data co-located with that of other tenants.

Read the paper.

> which would improve select performance

If you are trying to do this split for performance reasons, you and your team are definitely on the wrong path. Address the perf issues by identifying them and fix them appropriately. Read [How to analyze SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).  Multi-tenancy ain't cheap, and you need to plan ahead and have an answer to simple questions like 'how do I deploy the next version of my app, which includes a database modification?' and 'how to restore the data for one particular project?'.  The issues you see now are indicative of app tunning problems (hint: you're missing indexes).

As a personal experience note: I've seen databases with millions of objects in them (which the 'shared database, separate schema' approach is naturally going to cause), and it wasn't pretty... I hope *all* your DB administration is 100% scripted/automated now, expanding SSMS tree views with to select the 1 in 1M objects is not going to work.

Comment: Thanks. Going through the paper now.But wouldn't a database partition on ProjectID would be more beneficial here?

Comment: What do you mean by "database partition on ProjectID" ?

Comment: My first recommendation was doing a partition on database with projectID as reference. This would older project data goes into different partition which would be hopefully in different disks.

Comment: I would advise against partitioning the tables per project ID. You can, at the very best, make 15k partitions on a table, so you will end up mixing projects in a partition anyway. Partitioning has a cost, see [How To Decide if You Should Use Table Partitioning](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-decide-if-should-use-table-partitioning/).

Comment: As a first step I would start by making every clustered index key start with the project id.  It will give you most of the advantages you were after (as *every* query specifies a `project_id`, which I'm sure your app does, I hope), and the overhead/cost is smaller.

Comment: Also something for you to evaluate: impact of skew. Is often the case that that few tenants (projects) contain most data. It is often best to isolate these big impact tenants onto their dedicated DB(s) as a first step.

Comment: All in all there is no silver bullet. Multi-tenancy has many issues and none of the solutions is perfect. You and your team are best positioned to choose the right balance for you.

Comment: Thanks for all links shared. Definitely learned new things from the same.

Comment: That paper is available here: http://www.ijcsi.org/papers/IJCSI-9-6-3-198-204.pdf  And a newer one from Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/saas-tenancy-app-design-patterns

Answer (score 3):

Can't really add much to @RemusRusanu 's answer - maybe this should be made into a community wiki on this issue - it seems to crop up regularly in various shapes and forms.

There is, as Remus points out, no single answer to this question - basically, it's a series of compromises which boil down to **business** decisions less than technical ones.

For example, you write " This would be mean each table would contain at max 30K rows which would improve select performance" - err... no it won't. If you have 40 small tables being accessed at once, that will be as much (approx.) of a disk contention as one big table being accessed multiple times.

It's up to you to explain the issues to management having read Remus's link and other material that you can Google. I've worked with various companies which have taken differing approaches and I've written a bit about this issue myself ([1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103774/is-this-db-table-structure-sensible/103791#103791), [2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90092/what-would-be-the-primary-disadvantages-of-splitting-my-tables-into-table-spaces/90503#90503) & [3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74732/need-help-maintaining-multiple-databases-for-a-multi-tenant-application/74735#74735) and check the links within - esp. this [one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/one-big-database-vs-several-smaller-ones/7929#7929) -  the accepted answer to one thread). I'll try and write up a community wiki and submit it for approval. Best of luck with your situation.