# PostgreSQL: Having many instances of one application should I go with database per instance or schema per instance?

Tags: postgresql, architecture

*I am not asking for an opinion here. I need an answer supported by arguments.*

We have an web-application that will be installed multiple times on one server (one instance per customer). How should I organize the database for that case? Should I go with database per instance or schema per instance?

Option 1:

- DB: appname_customername1, SCHEMA: appname
- DB: appname_customername2, SCHEMA: appname
- DB: appname_customername3, SCHEMA: appname

Option 2:

- DB: appname, SCHEMA: appname_customername1
- DB: appname, SCHEMA: appname_customername2
- DB: appname, SCHEMA: appname_customername3

How the two approaches compare in sense of performance and memory usage? Is there a difference in administrative tasks/costs?

NOTES:

- NO data is shared between tenants and never will be
- There is no shared master data and it will never exist

Comment: This all depends on where you ever need to access data from multiple tenants

Comment: one advantage of schemas over databases is ability to join shared "master" data with per-tenant tables, without any need of cross-database synchronization.

Comment: From what you've written, it appears that you should go for the separate schema approach since you have no shared data between the clients - a major reason to go for multi-tenancy. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199470/34007), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/74507/34007) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/90503/34007) and links within those threads for discusstion.